# Should I use in-radius or in-cone to define vision in NetLogo 3D?

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to make two models, one in base NetLogo and the other in the 3D version. In the 3D version how do I define a spherical visual range rather than a circular one? Is it by using in-radius or in-cone or perhaps something different?

Hope you can help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm not used to 3D Netlogo but I believe you could use In-cone to see what's in front of you. Radius is used to know what's around the turtles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NetLogo 3D, `in-radius` is spherical.

Why not just try it? It should only take you a minute to verify this by experiment using NetLogo 3D's Command Center.